# ERROR in No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule' ngx-rocket metronic theme

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular8, metronic

#### Command

- [ ] new
- [x] build
- [x] serve
- [ ] test
- [ ] e2e
- [ ] generate
- [ ] add
- [ ] update
- [ ] lint
- [ ] xi18n
- [ ] run
- [ ] config
- [ ] help
- [ ] version
- [ ] doc

#### Is this a regression?

It started happening in the same version without any version upgrade of any sort.

### Description

There are 2 parts of the BUG. 1 during *serve* and 1 during *build* creation.

#### Description During Serve

If I need to tell this clearly, it can only be said that this bug occurred while doing development, And no changes to AppModule was made during that time. You hit npm start and you get the following error:
*ERROR in No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'.*

You save any file again and it will start compiling again and compile successfully.

#### Description during build

It runs the build and fails with the following error:
*ERROR in members.hasOwnProperty is not a function*

### Minimal Reproduction

I don't know how to reproduce it. It has occurred during development and without any upgrade to any packages.

### Exception or Error

#### Exception on SERVE:

No exception can be found except for the above error as told in the description.

#### Exception on BUILD:

No exception could be found except for the above error. But I will still put some details here:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.12.1
3 info using node@v12.13.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle xxxx-ers@1.0.0~prebuild: xxxx-ers@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle xxxx-ers@1.0.0~build: xxxx-ers@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle xxxx-ers@1.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle xxxx-ers@1.0.0~build: PATH: ...
9 verbose lifecycle xxxx-ers@1.0.0~build: CWD: C:\Projects\ERS\Repositories\xxxx.ERS.UI
10 silly lifecycle xxxx-ers@1.0.0~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm run env -s && ng build --prod' ]
11 silly lifecycle xxxx-ers@1.0.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle xxxx-ers@1.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: xxxx-ers@1.0.0 build: `npm run env -s && ng build --prod`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid xxxx-ers@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Projects\ERS\Repositories\xxxx.ERS.UI
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v12.13.1
19 verbose npm  v6.12.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error xxxx-ers@1.0.0 build: `npm run env -s && ng build --prod`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the xxxx-ers@1.0.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

### My Environment

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.22
Node: 12.13.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.14
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router, service-worker

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.800.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.800.6
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.800.6
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.800.6
@angular-devkit/core               8.0.6
@angular-devkit/schematics         8.3.22
@angular/cdk                       8.2.3
@angular/cli                       8.3.22
@angular/material                  8.2.3
@angular/material-moment-adapter   8.2.3
@ngtools/webpack                   8.0.6
@schematics/angular                8.3.22
@schematics/update                 0.803.22
rxjs                               6.5.4
typescript                         3.4.5
webpack                            4.30.0
```

**Anything else relevant?**
I have performed almost all the work arounds I found in the issues earlier reported but none of them worked. Like, adding the AppModule to `tsconfig.app.json`. Making sure `const bootstrap = () => platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);` is in the one line in `main.ts`. and host of other steps. But none of them works. Please help.

### My main.ts

```
/*
 * Entry point of the application.
 * Only platform bootstrapping code should be here.
 * For app-specific initialization, use `app/app.component.ts`.
 */

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from '@app/app.module';
import { environment } from '@env/environment';
import { hmrBootstrap } from './hmr';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

const bootstrap = () => platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);

if (environment.hmr) {
  hmrBootstrap(module, bootstrap);
} else {
  bootstrap().catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

### My App.module.ts

```
// Angular
import { BrowserModule, HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { GestureConfig, MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material';
import { OverlayModule } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
// Perfect Scroll bar
import { PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG, PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface } from 'ngx-perfect-scrollbar';
// SVG inline
import { InlineSVGModule } from 'ng-inline-svg';
// Env
import { environment } from '@env/environment';
// Hammer JS
import 'hammerjs';
// Copmponents
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
// Modules
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { ThemeModule } from './views/theme/theme.module';
// Partials
import { PartialsModule } from './views/partials/partials.module';
// Layout Services
import {
  //DataTableService,
  //FakeApiService,
  KtDialogService,
  LayoutConfigService,
  LayoutRefService,
  MenuAsideService,
  MenuConfigService,
  MenuHorizontalService,
  PageConfigService,
  SplashScreenService,
  SubheaderService
} from './core/_base/layout';
// CRUD
import { LayoutUtilsService, TypesUtilsService } from './core/_base/crud';
// Config
import { LayoutConfig } from './core/_config/layout.config';
// Highlight JS
import { HIGHLIGHT_OPTIONS, HighlightLanguage } from 'ngx-highlightjs';
import * as typescript from 'highlight.js/lib/languages/typescript';
import * as scss from 'highlight.js/lib/languages/scss';
import * as xml from 'highlight.js/lib/languages/xml';
import * as json from 'highlight.js/lib/languages/json';

// tslint:disable-next-line:class-name
const DEFAULT_PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG: PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface = {
  wheelSpeed: 0.5,
  swipeEasing: true,
  minScrollbarLength: 40,
  maxScrollbarLength: 300
};

export function initializeLayoutConfig(appConfig: LayoutConfigService) {
  // initialize app by loading default demo layout config
  return () => {
    if (appConfig.getConfig() === null) {
      appConfig.loadConfigs(new LayoutConfig().configs);
    }
  };
}

export function hljsLanguages(): HighlightLanguage[] {
  return [
    { name: 'typescript', func: typescript },
    { name: 'scss', func: scss },
    { name: 'xml', func: xml },
    { name: 'json', func: json }
  ];
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    // environment.isMockEnabled
    //   ? HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(FakeApiService, {
    //       passThruUnknownUrl: true,
    //       dataEncapsulation: false
    //     })
    //   : [],
    //NgxPermissionsModule.forRoot(),
    PartialsModule,
    CoreModule,
    OverlayModule,
    //AuthModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot(),
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    InlineSVGModule.forRoot(),
    ThemeModule
  ],
  exports: [],
  providers: [
    LayoutConfigService,
    LayoutRefService,
    MenuConfigService,
    PageConfigService,
    KtDialogService,
    //DataTableService,
    SplashScreenService,
    {
      provide: PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG,
      useValue: DEFAULT_PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG
    },
    {
      provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG,
      useClass: GestureConfig
    },
    {
      // layout config initializer
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeLayoutConfig,
      deps: [LayoutConfigService],
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: HIGHLIGHT_OPTIONS,
      useValue: { languages: hljsLanguages }
    },
    // template services
    SubheaderService,
    MenuHorizontalService,
    MenuAsideService,
    //HttpUtilsService,
    TypesUtilsService,
    LayoutUtilsService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

### My app-routing.module.ts

```
// Angular
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
// Components
import { BaseComponent } from './views/theme/base/base.component';
import { ErrorPageComponent } from './views/theme/content/error-page/error-page.component';
// Auth
import { AuthGuard } from './core/auth';
import { AuthenticationGuard  } from "@app/core";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'auth', loadChildren: () => import('../app/views/pages/auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule) },

  {
    path: '',
    component: BaseComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: () => import('../app/views/pages/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'kiosk',
        loadChildren: () => import('../app/views/pages/kiosk/kiosk.module').then(m => m.KioskModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'registration',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('../app/views/pages/registeration/registeration.module').then(c => c.RegisterationModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'error/403',
        component: ErrorPageComponent,
        data: {
          type: 'error-v6',
          code: 403,
          title: '403... Access forbidden',
          desc: "Looks like you don't have permission to access for requested page.<br> Please, contact administrator"
        }
      },
      { path: 'error/:type', component: ErrorPageComponent },
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' }
    ]
  },

  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'error/403', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

This issue can also be found at github:
[ERROR in No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16706)

Any help would be appreciated. Please help as I need to create a production build and deploy the application to a server, but is not able to do this.

Comment: Guys I have been able to solve the both issues, but haven't been able to pin point the exact reason why those issues were being generated. I isolated the issue to a SERVICE and tweaked it to get things working. More details can be read in the github issue above. Will answer my question once I get time and is able to pinpoint the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it turned out that the community found the problem which was causing this issue. One of which is the problem with the angular compiler itself. Please refer to the following links for details:

[NG Serve issue resolution](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35143#issuecomment-582050978)

[NG Build issue resolution](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35143#issuecomment-582065681)

Hope this helps.